# Why does parseInt fail to test Arrays properly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parseint

Given:

```
var obj={0:21,1:22}
```

and

```
var arr=[21,22]
```

Why does `parseInt(obj)` return `NaN`, but `parseInt(arr)` returns `21`?

I had a function where I was either going to pass an `int`, a hash type `object` or a plain `array`.  I was expecting `parseInt` to return `NaN` for both `object` and `array`, thus simplifying argument checking.  What gives?

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt()` at all? The only two things I would use it for are (a) non-base 10 input, and (b) parsing an input string in a known format like a CSS `"10px"` where I just want the `10` part. I believe `Number([21,22])` returns `NaN`, as does the unary plus operator `+[21,23]`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Why not?  `if isNaN(parseInt(argument1))...`.  Quick and easy.  What's the harm?  I'm not being flip.  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: If `argument1` is the string `"123abc"`, that's not a valid number, but `parseInt("123abc")` returns `123`. If that's the result you actually *want*, then sure, use `parseInt()`, but in my experience it's pretty rare for that to make sense (I gave an example already where it does make sense). If you want to test that a function argument is *already* a number (and not an object or array) you can use the `typeof` operator.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I get your point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `parseInt` tries to coerce the first argument to a string before parsing to an integer. `String(obj)` returns `"[object Object]"` and can't be parsed, but `String([21,23])` returns `"21,23"`, which `parseInt` parses until it reaches the unparseable char.

See [the `parseInt` spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix):

> Let `inputString` be ? ToString(`string`).

(Coerce the input to a string).

> If S contains a code unit that is not a radix-R digit, let Z be the substring of S consisting of all code units before the first such code unit; otherwise, let Z be S.

(Drop any part of the string starting with non-digit character, so `"21,23"` -> `"21"`).

Comment: This is correct. String representation of an array is result of joining the array elements.

Comment: "This is because parseInt tries to coerce the argument to a string"? The documentation infers otherwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: That's it.  Amazing the amount of subtle nuances within programming languages

Comment: @AlMamun Why do you think the docs say otherwise? Non-string args converted to a string, yes?

Comment: To me the document says parseInt tries to coerce values from string to number.

Comment: The first argument is coerced to a string, *then* parsed to a number. The question was about what happens with non-string input.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity here.